# What to do to recover after deploying a new shopping cart / site and Google smacks you?

Tags: seo, google-search, url, 301-redirect, ecommerce

I recently deployed a reworked online store that was previously built with a system that suddenly went out of business.  It was a rush and I ended up with new URLs for all products with even some different content.  We were doing fantastic with SEO to now being essentially completely gone from Google.

I'm trying to figure out how to recover from this situation and get back to where we were just a month and a half ago.

Is it just a matter of recreating the URL mapping the way it used to be and/or mapping a bunch (thousands) of 301 redirects?  Or is there more to it?  Are there any guides or discussions about how to methodically going about fixing this or am I just screwed at this point?

Comment: See also: [How to recover from a google penalty](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/93502/how-to-recover-from-a-google-penalty)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you translate on english this article i wrote, it describe the full process of successfull seo migration.
 https://www.410-gone.fr/seo/optimisation-on-site/migration-https-certificat-ssl/refonte-site-redirection.html